# MySQL. Error code 1136

Tags: mysql

i´m trying to insert some values in mysql but i get error code 1136, i verified and one of the values is auto-increment so i don't have to enter that one and the rest give a total of 18 which are exactly the total values i'm writting, could somebody help me?

This is the table im using:

```
FIELD               TYPE    NULL  KEY  DEFAULT  EXTRA
id_display_detail   int(11) NO    PRI           auto_increment
amount              double  NO          
amount_lc           double  NO          
exchange            double  NO          
company        varchar(10)  NO          
date               datetime NO          
description    varchar(100) NO          
document_number varchar(20) NO          
document_type   varchar(2)  NO          
posting_key     varchar(3)  NO          
special_gl      varchar(1)  NO          
status           int(11)    NO          
voucher_number  varchar(40) NO          
year             int(11)    NO  MUL     
id_currency      int(11)    NO  MUL     
id_employee      int(11)    NO  MUL     
credit           bit(1)     YES         
card_type       varchar(45) NO          
line_item        int(11)    YES
```

And this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO display_detail VALUES (300,300,0,'2001','2016-04-11',
   'Downpayment ZM00080621','2000010802','ZP','29','R',0,
     'GCCTEA 8062130',2016,1,1561,0,NULL,1);
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: for PRI key you must add NULL, i.e. `...VALUES (NULL, 300,300...)` or to specify in which columns you want to insert data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing the column name 
(Because the id is automatic the values you provided don't math the number of column so must declare the column name)

```
 INSERT INTO display_detail ( amount,
        amount_lc ,
        exchange ,
        company  ,
        date  ,
        description ,
        document_number,
        document_type ,
        posting_key ,
        special_gl ,
        status  ,
        voucher_number  ,
        year  ,
        id_currency ,
        id_employee  ,
        credit ,
        card_type ,
        line_item  )   VALUES (300,300,0,'2001','2016-04-11',
           'Downpayment ZM00080621','2000010802','ZP','29','R',0,
             'GCCTEA 8062130',2016,1,1561,0,NULL,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> and one of the values is auto-increment so i don't have to enter that one

That doesn't change the fact that the number of values in your VALUES clause has to match the number of columns.

You need to either specify NULL as the value for the auto_increment column - or specify a column list after INSERT first.

Comment: Oh so i was doing that wrong, thanks a lot CBroe (Y)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you aren't listing the columns in your INSERT statement.  A MySQL query typically looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
...;
```

(Taken from: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/insert.php)

The final query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO display_detail 
(amount, amount_lc, exchange, company, date, description, 
document_number, document_type, posting_key,special_gl,status,voucher_number,year,
id_currency, id_employee, credit, card_type, line_item) 
    VALUES (300,300,0,'2001','2016-04-11',
       'Downpayment ZM00080621','2000010802','ZP','29','R',0,
         'GCCTEA 8062130',2016,1,1561,0,NULL,1);
```

Comment: I considered doing that but i thought it wasn´t gonna help, next time i´ll know, thank you CSLearner